# Добавление пользователя в vboxusers

Tags: virtualbox, linux

Доброго времени суток. На компе ubuntu 12.10. Поставил на вирт машину windows 7 32bit Ultimate. Все гостевые дополнения и пакет расширений поставил. Выдаёт такую ошибку:

> Не удалось получить доступ к USB-подсистеме.В данный момент VirtualBox не может использовать устройства USB. Вы можете исправить данную проблему, добавив текущего пользователя в группу 'vboxusers'. Для получения более детальных объяснений следуйте указаниям руководства пользователя.

в деталях к ошибке пишет:

> `Код ошибки: NS_ERROR_ЦитатаFAILURE (0x00004005)Компонент: HostИнтерфейс: IHost {30678943-32df-4830-b413-931b25ac86a0}Вызванный интерфейс: IMachine {22781af3-1c96-4126-9edf-67a020e0e858}`

Посмотрел текущего пользователя на всякий случай командой whoami. Текущего пользователя пытался добавить как в мануале

> `sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers in43sh`

Пользователь вроде как в группе, но ошибка та же.

Comment: команда id что покажет?

Comment: uid=1000(in43sh) gid=1000(in43sh) группы=1000(in43sh),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),107(lpadmin),124(sambashare)

Comment: А ну да группы то нету, тогда groupadd vboxusers сначала, а потом добавляйте.

Comment: группу я добавил, и в ней есть мой пользователь:vboxusers:x:125:in43shно virtualbox всё равно требует, чтобы я добавил своего пользователя в эту группу. как такое возможно?

Comment: Так, я usdfs смонтирован?

Comment: нет, а что это и как это сделать?

Comment: Узнаешь сначала gid группы vboxusers, cat /etc/group | grep vboxusers. Потом пишешь в /etc/fstab такой маунтпоинт: где devgid gid группы vboxusers.none /proc/bus/usb usbfs devgid=??? ,devmode=664 0 0потом mount -a, profit?!!

Comment: выдаёт такую ошибку[mntent]: предупреждение: no final newline at the end of /etc/fstabmount: точка монтирования /proc/bus/usb не существует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем смысл в том, вам необходимо смонтировать usbfs, и разрешить к ней доступ пользователя от которого запускается virtualbox, либо целой группе vboxusers, предварительно включив в нее нужных пользователей. Теперь я узнал что в новой бубунте usbfs через попу достается так:

```
mount --bind /dev/bus/usb /proc/bus/usb
```

А после этого уже попробуйте

```
 none /proc/bus/usb usbfs devgid=??? ,devmode=664 0 0
```

в fstab.

Comment: sudo mount --bind /dev/bus/usb /proc/bus/usb  такая ошибка:  mount: точка монтирования /proc/bus/usb не существуетпробую создать  sudo mkdir -p /proc/bus/usb  такая ошибка:  mkdir: невозможно создать каталог «/proc/bus/usb»: Нет такого файла или каталога  как такое возможно?

Comment: А /proc/bus/ то есть? Попробуй так sudo mount --bind /dev/bus/ /proc/bus/

Comment: спасибо огромное! всё заработало. правда я так и не понял, почему :) ведь мне нужно было добавить пользователя в группу, а я смонтировал файловую систему usb зачем-то. если не сложно, объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Проще говоря, ваша система виртуализации захотела (вы попросили) получить доступ в usb устройствам, для этого ей необходимо получить данные с вирт.псевдо-файловой системы usbfs на которой она работает, в ней есть информация о подключенных устройствах и т.д. Еще проще говоря смонтировав usbfs - это "дырка" с информацией о usb хоста, которой уже пользуется прикладной софт, типа virtualbox. А пользователь в группе  это всего лишь пермишен который дает право пользоваться файловой системой.

Comment: что означает "пермишен"? я погуглил, но так и не нашёл.

Comment: пермишен = permission

Comment: ещё раз спасибо! извиняюсь, что тупил :)